# PC will not boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, surface

Good day all. I have been working on this problem for a month now. I have a ms surface go 2 with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. No windows, yes I know now I should have left windows on it! Never, even with windows would it boot from restart to a usb. Using the grub command line Ive reconized the usb with the linux live on it. i can ls through and see everything. i even made it restart into a memtest file on that partition of that usb from the grub shell. Here is what i can see;

grub> ls (hd0,gpt1) <already verified to be the path to usb needed

```
 partition hd0,gpt1: filesystem type iso9660 - label 'ubuntu 23.01.1 and64' - last modification time 2023-10-16 11:29:57 monday, uuid 2023-10-16-11-29-57-00 - partition start at 32 kib - total size 5047348kib
```

grub> ls (hd0,gpt1)/

```
boot/ boot.catalog casper/ dists/ efi/ install/ md5sum.txt pool/ preseed/ ubuntu
```

grub> ls -lh (hd0,gpt1)/boot

```
  dir  "date" grub/
  144.96k "date" memtest86+x64.bin   <--- I made this file boot from grub shell
```

I did this by;

grub> set root=(hd0,gpt1)

grub> linux boot/memtest86+x64.bin

grub> boot

output of ls (hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub

dir fonts; 669 grub.cfg; dir 1386-pc/; 404 loopback.cfg; dir x86_64-efi/

Something in here must make this live usb load from grub.

I have also tried to add a menu entry in   /etc/grub.d/40_custom.
This is what I entered;

menuentry "Boot from USB Drive" {
set root=UUID=
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID= ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img

with appropriate alteration in uuid spot.
I than;

sudo update-grub

According to where I got that from it should put a option to boot from usb on the grub menu. It did not.
Before doing all this i did the obvious firsts. Set usb to first option in grub menu, tried more than one usb. Also bought a usb c so as to not use the hub incase that was stopping it. Ive watched many vids with this same device being booted from a usb, I dont understand why this one will not.

Edit for first questions; bios is up to date as of the fall. No windows to update and read about doing through linux but would rather not if possible. Secure boot is off. Trusted boot i just disabled. No error msg

Comment: Have you updated the BIOS on your Surface Go 2 to the latest firmware? Try resetting your BIOS to default settings and checking Trusted Boot and Fast Boot settings. Are you getting any error messages at all?

Comment: Your paths are wrong for the img and initrd, they are now in /boot, no longer in / .  After your update-grub, track down why the new entry does not show: Is it in /boot/grub/grub.cfg? Is the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg using the correct UUID for your root?

Answer (score 1):

My Microsoft Surface Go 2 would not boot any form of USB. Here's how I made it work. The answer came from here, but in regards to being stuck at the grub shell on a normal PC. For the surface you need to have a keyboard you can plug in. You'll  need a hub so you can plug in this and a USB, also its only a USB-C. Spamming your Esc should kick you into your grub shell.  From here use `ls` and figure out which hard drive is your USB. I noted what was there without the USB, rebooted to grub with USB in and the extra is your USB. Use that designation (ex; (hd0,1) in my case it was actually (hd0,gpt1)) in these commands in place of (hd).

ls (hd) #to look into it, in my case i got this; partition hd0,got: Filesystem type iso9660 - label 'Ubuntu 23.10.1 amd64' + some mod info and uuid#, and size info

ls (hd)/ #your looking for the boot file. the writeup I read said it may be boot/ or boot/grub.

ls (hd)/boot/grub #should return something like this; fonts/ grub.cfg i386-pc/ loopback.cfg x86_64-efi/ (this was my precise return)

After doing the above to find /boot/grub the following worked for me.

```
set prefix=(hd)/boot/grub  
set root=(hd)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
boot
```

In my case after the boot command it went to the grub menu for Ubuntu live giving me the normal option to try or install. These units in particular seem to be a little more difficult.